# Sendgrid template handling unkown json object

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I would like to "stringify" the object what the sendgrid template received. With other words, How can I use an unknown structured object with the sendgrid template.

**Example:**

My object:

```
{"test": {"foo": { "bar": {"foo2": "bar2"}}}
```

My sendgrid template:

```
... what is inside the test object: {{ test }}
```

And the result is:

... what is inside the test object: [object Object]

However I would like to something like this:

... what is inside the test object: {"foo": { "bar": {"foo2": "bar2"}}}

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score -1):

TEST DATA:

```
{"test": {"foo": { "bar": {"foo2": "bar2"}}}}
```

HTML:

```
{{test.foo.bar.foo2}}
```

Render:

```
bar2
```

Comment: You misunderstand my question. I would like to Render this: `{"foo": { "bar": {"foo2": "bar2"}}}`